# отключение кнопок системного меню

Tags: delphi

Работающий под стандартным стилем (Windows) код отключения кнопок системного меню

```
EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(AWnd, False), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_GRAYED)
```

не работает при применении иных стилей. Есть у кого решение проблемы?

Comment: `TForm.BorderIcons` вам не подходит?

Comment: Это понятно. меня заинтересовало то, что в поставляемых стилях, при просмотре редактором, есть соответствующие изображения значит должен быть и механизм их применения?

Comment: да черт его знает, вы последние версии делфи пользуете? Ибо возможно в первых выпусках а-ля `хе2` это было упущено.Также может чем то поможет вот [эта штука](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils)

Comment: странно, что на английском сайте этот вопрос тоже задавался, однако решения и там не было, кроме как обработать `CloseQuery`